# Reactjs: setState from outside of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css'
import Tools from './components/class/Tools'
import Loading from './components/inc/Loading'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        Tools.showLoading(); // or new Tools();
    }

    render() {  
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Loading />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

> Loading.js:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Loading extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            display: 'none'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="loading" style={{display: this.state.display}}>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

> Tools.js

```
export default class Tools extends React.Component {
    static showLoading(){ // or non-static
        Loading.setState ...
    }
}
```

I want change `display` state from outside of `Loading` component.

I use `Loading` in whole my project and I want create function for handle it.

Example for another use:

```
function xxx(){
    Tools.showLoading(); // or new Tools();
}
```

Or:

```
<span onClick={Tools.showLoading(); // or new Tools();}></span>
```

Actually, I want create only one function to manage and handle display of `Loading`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Tools.js`

```js
let loadingStateSetter = null

export function setLoadingStateSetter(setter) {
    loadingStateSetter = setter
    return () => loadingStateSetter = null
}

export function setLoadingState(value) {
    if (loadingStateSetter !== null) loadingStateSetter(value)
}
```

In `Loading.js`:

```js
import { setLoadingStateSetter } from './Tools.js'

export default class Loading extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            display: 'none'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="loading" style={{display: this.state.display}}>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.removeStateSetter = setLoadStateSetter((value) => {
            this.setState((state) => ({
                ...state,
                display: value,
            })
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.removeStateSetter()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```js
import { setLoadingState } from './Tools.js'

function xxx(){
    setLoadingState('some value')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can easily expose a setState function externally, it acts just like any other function, its not usually a good idea.  You should instead consider rewriting your Loading component to use the property object to tell it if its loading and track the loading state higher up the component tree where it is accessible by things that would want to change its status.

Comment: Buy this way, I most repeat my code for every where

Answer (score 0):

I think you can using redux as store manager global state
https://redux.js.org/
another way pass it through props and handle it at parent component

Comment: I use redux, but useSelector not work in classes. only work in native function

Comment: if you want to use loading global state just wapper loading outside your component and set state through redux.